# Angular environment variables on an ejected project

Tags: angular, webpack

**What I want to achieve?**
Generating Environments variable depending on which NODE_ENV I am currently compiling on an **Ejected project** (ng eject).
The same of targeting the environment using the Angular Cli:
`ng build --prod || ng build --dev`.

**What I tried?**

1. Setting my NODE_ENV in my scripts:

*package.json*

```
   ...
   "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
   "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
   ...
```

2. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387864/angular-cli-environment-file-replacement-is-broken-after-switch-to-webpack-wit), I changed my AotPlugin in webpack and replace it with:

   ```
   const environmentFiles = {
   'development': 'environments/environment.dev.ts',
   'production': 'environments/environment.prod.ts',
   };


   ...
   new AotPlugin({
   ...
    "hostReplacementPaths":
      "environments/environment.ts": environmentFiles[process.env.NODE_ENV]
   ```

3. Try to run: *npm run-script build:prod* 
   But the AotPlugin doesn't look to replace (*hostReplacementPaths*) for me the Environment variables file (*environment.dev.ts* || *environment.prod.ts*).

Any idea?

**Similiar questions:**

[Environment file replacement is broken after switching to webpack...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387864/angular-cli-environment-file-replacement-is-broken-after-switch-to-webpack-wit)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just reverted my ejected project and back to use the CLI!
But... I solved it just copying and pasting my environments into environment.ts with a prebuild script!

```
"prebuild:dev": "cp environment/environment.dev.ts environment/environment.ts"
```

you can also set your NODE variables to apply your conditions into your code:
[How to set Environment variables from within package.json [Node.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json-node-js)

For example:

```
npm run prebuild:dev
// will build my dev environment
npm run prebuild:prod
// will build my prod environment
```

Comment: If you are on windows, you have to change the slashes and the copy command cp to copy like so:

"prebuild:dev": "copy environment\\environment.dev.ts src\\environment\\environment.ts"