# Webpack config for angular-cli project

Tags: angular, webpack

I have angular-cli project with 3 environments files:

```
 1. environment.prod.ts
 2. environment.dev.ts
 3. environment.stages.ts
```

I want to build project on the server(not put dist folder to the server, but run webpack build on server). I run `ng eject` to get webpack.config.js, but when i run `webpack --env=prod or webpack --env=dev` it make bundle only for environment.prod.ts, but i need to make bundle for other environment too. How can I do this?

P.S. First of all sorry for my bad English. If you don't understand what i need or if you need more information, please just ask me to correct my answer)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387864/angular-cli-environment-file-replacement-is-broken-after-switch-to-webpack-wit
I found this answer, but i don't know how specify NODE_ENV for each env. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Set the `NODE_ENV` before webpack command.  E.g. `NODE_ENV='production' webpack -p`

Comment: I try `npm run build NODE_ENV='dev'` and get TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at WebpackCompilerHost._normalizePath

Comment: maybe I do something wrong? I add `var NODE_ENV;` into my webpack.congif.js, cause without it, i get error `NODE_ENV` is not defined. But now in my editor NODE_ENV look like unused variable.

Comment: Thank you, Gowrav. Now workin fine, I just add `NODE_ENV=env` to `module.exports` in webpack.config.js.